# Rails Tutorial: Duplicate method names, remember and remember(user), forget and forget(user)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, duplicates, railstutorial.org

In chapter 8 of the Rails Tutorial, there are four methods defined. One is called remember (listing 8.32) with no arguments, another is called remember(user) (listing 8.35). Then there is a method called forget (listing 8.38) with no arguments, and a forget(user) method (listing 8.39).

I understand the logic behind the authentication machinery, what I don't get is why these method pairs don't conflict or collide between each other, having the same name, that is.

Is it because of one method having no arguments passed to it and the other requiring one? Is that how Rails can tell them apart? Or is something else going on so that Rails knows which method to call.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Update: Thanks to a suggestion in the comments, I'll reproduce the code here:

In the file **user.rb** which is the User model, there are these methods:

```
def remember
  self.remember_token = User.new_token
  update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
end
...
def forget
  update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
end
...
```

And in the file **sessions_helper.rb**, which is where the helpers for the Session model reside, the author defines these two methods:

```
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
```

What's bothering me is why the code works even though there are two methods with the same name (even though one accepts no arguments and the other accepts one, the user).

I have to add that the sessions_helper.rb was included in the Application Helper file, so they are universal.

Comment: can you post some code that's bothering you, so that we can have a look at what's really going on?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I edited the question to include the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby doesn't support method overriding, if several
methods with the same name are defined in a class - the latest overwrites
previous definitions.

In this case, the methods that are in **user.rb** can only be accessed/invoked through a user object.

```
def remember(user)
    user.remember // invoked by user object
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

You will find that if you send a non-user object to your helper method, it will return an error as this method can only be accessed by the user object.

This works the same if you were to define methods with the same name in separate classes as they can only be accessed through the respective classes.

If you were to include your helper in a controller and add a method in your controller with the same name as the helper method, your controller method would override the former method. Which would be the same as adding two methods with the same name in the same controller. As stated above, ruby doesn't allow method overriding.

Answer (score 0):

`forget` is an instance method of the `User` class.
`forget(user)` is an instance method of the `SessionsHelper` module.

Yes. `SessionsHelper` was included earlier in the `ApplicationHelper` but the `User` class does not inherit from neither.

That's why there is no conflict between these two instance methods. They're just different instance methods in different scopes with the same name.